# Doing perspective correction per component in a fragment shader

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, shader

I'm currently trying to emulate an NVIDIA GPU but I have some problems with setting input variables from a shader. I require something like this in glsl:

```
layout(location = 0) in noperspective vec4 value1;
layout(location = 0) in smooth vec4 value1_alias;
```

Sadly that code is illegal in openGL. Interpolation aliasing is not permitted. In general, I want certain components of the vector to be "perspective corrected" and others to be obtained linearly. it's vital that this is done in the correct order for each component. I also must use the exact same attribute slot (location), I'm emulating a GPU thus each attribute is set by it and I cannot duplicate values.

What I tried doing was to take all values as noperspective and do the perspective correction inside the shader. My approach was simply multiply the value by `(1 / glFragCoord.w)`. Sadly this does not seem to work. I'm not sure if the theory I'm following is flawed or the `glFragCoord.w` value I'm recieving from my fragment shader is incorrect. (I do set `glPosition` with w as 1.0)

With all this in mind? What approach could I take to do the perspective correction on independent values?

Comment: must be the same location. I cannot duplicate it as I'm emulating a GPU.